# How to set node environment variables during cloud provisioning -terraform?

Tags: node.js, bash, amazon-web-services, docker, terraform

I am using react as frontend and node js as backend an I performing cloud provisioning, a new ec2 instance using terraform. I haven't started to write the terraform script yet.

But I am writing bash script in the user data value to execute on the new instance created. I am writing this userdata attribute of terraform ,just that I can know whether my flow is right or wrong.

And in here , I feel the flow is good correct me if I am wrong .

**Note 1:** This provision happens with a single click on frontend by admin and a new instance is created with the front end and backend along with the new environment variables , ( because here Paypal client ID and google auth key is remaining unique for each instance so how do I set those environment variables dynamically )

**Note 2:** Since I am having my backend as node js, I have the form data {google auth client ID , Paypal Cliend ID} there which I receive by the requested user submitted on the frontend, After admin accepts the request all this provisioning should happen automatically .
And upon that button click by admin, I am calling the terraform script in the backend node js to spin up a new instance , there in the userdata attribute of terraform I am using the following bash script . How do I set the form data values {google auth client ID , Paypal Cliend ID} in my bash script .

So what is the method which can set these node js environment variables at time of cloud provisioning?

this terraform/main.tf will be called by node js so how can node js set the environment variables of frontend and backend of the new instance created

terraform /main.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "default" {
  ami                    = var.ami-id
  iam_instance_profile   = var.iam-instance-profile
  instance_type          = var.instance-type
  key_name               = var.key-pair
  private_ip             = var.private-ip
  subnet_id              = var.subnet-id
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.vpc-security-group-ids

  user_data = <<EOF
sudo su -
yum install updates -y
yum install mysql -y
yum install nginx -y
sudo service nginx start
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install node 
mkdir cd /var/apps
cd /var/apps
yum install git -y
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/frontend.git
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/backend.git
cd frontend && npm install
//I want to set some node env variables for my front end here
//like NODE.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID='0000aaaaa' NODE.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID='12321ewre'
npm run build
cd ..
cd backend && npm install
//I want to set some node env variables for my backend here
//like NODE.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID='0000aaaaa' NODE.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID='12321ewre'
npm start
rm -r /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
cp backend/nginx/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
sudo service nginx restart
EOF

  tags = {
    Name = var.name
  }
}
```

NOTE : I do have a .env.production and .env.development files, but I don't know how to overwrite them with values from node js to here

Comment: You will need to export the required variables along with running npm start in one bash process and so bash -c "export PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID='0000aaaaa' && export GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID='12321ewre' && npm start"

Comment: Well, thank you and how do I set the values from node js to that bash script

Comment: the nodejs code with pick up the session environmental variables by using the NODE.env convention. You need to export the variables to the bash session so that nodejs can interrogate the entries using the bash -c example I gave before,

Comment: So you mean, in node js I set NODE.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID=282H3BFJJD and I can access it in bash script ?

Comment: No. They are environmental variables and so shouldn't be set within nodejs at all. They need to be set/exported at bash script execution level and then only referenced by nodejs.

Comment: Change the command npm start in the script to ..... bash -c "export PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID='0000aaaaa' && export GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID='12321ewre' && npm start"

Comment: I have modified please check this is going to be a terraform file, inside which there is a userdata attribute which is a bash script which will run on new instance so how can set the environment variable inside that bash script of that userdata attribute of main.tf file . this tf file will run by node js file execution manually

Comment: Whatever is executing terraform will need to pass the two variables PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID & GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID in so that you can then access them in terraform and then set them as environment variables within your instances, so they can be consumed by node.

When terraform is executed you can pass in variables as such: `terraform apply -var="paypal_client_id=000"`. You should then look terraform `data "template_file"` resource, so you can set the value of the variables within your script.

Comment: If I can set the var in the command terraform apply , I would have done it in npm start itself as @aman-sailopal said in the bash script in the user_data attribute but how do I set the values from the node js to this script ? I am doing this cloud provisioning from my parent website server , where node js is the backend , upon post request I have to do this entire cloud porvisioning , so when I have the data in my node js from post request how do I set those values to the bash script which I am executing in terraform ?